# Parabolic motion with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, jquery-animate, motion

I'm making a script to simulate the parabolic motion of a ball. I do not understand where I'm wrong, it works with jquery. I think it's a problem in the frame.

```
    <html>
     <head>
        <script>
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var x = 100;

            function init() {
            setInterval("draw()", 1);
            }

            function draw() {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, motoPar(x + 2, 0, 100, 100), 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                ctx.stroke();
            } 

            function motoPar(x, x0, Vx, Vy){
                var y;
                var g = 3;
                y = -1/2 * g * (x * x) / (Vx * Vx) + Vy / Vx * x;
                return y;
            }
        </script>
</head>

<body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
        </canvas>
</body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you have a second unclosed `body` tag?

Comment: sorry mistake in copying

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your ball moving, though not parabolically.

**1** Wrap your starter code in window.onload and also invoke init() inside of it (though do keep the var declarations for c, ctx, and x as globals -- ie outside of the window.onload function)):

```
    var c, ctx, x;

    window.onload = function() { // <--  invoked when page ready
       c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); // c is null if DOM isn't done
       ctx = c.getContext("2d");
       x = 100;
       init(); // <-- make sure to call :)
    }
```

**2** Pass the identifier `draw` itself to setInterval (function names are variables too)

```
     setInterval(draw, 1);
```

3 That will get you a ball drawn but it won't be moving. As far as the motion, I'll leave that to you, but I threw in a `++x` into the middle of the `draw()` function which at least gets the ball to slide to the bottom right